# Pass a dynamic object type to method

Tags: c#

I have a method that return data from API ,the returned data will be differ upon the return object type.How can I do that?

```
public static dynamic getObjectDataRequest(string ControllerName,string ActionName,dynamic returnObj,object Params)
    {
        string URL = getAPIURL();
        string RequestURL = URL + "/" + ControllerName + "/" + ActionName + "?";
        string p = Params.ToString().Replace("{","").Replace("}","").Replace(",", "&");
            RequestURL +=p ;
        RequestURL = RequestURL.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RequestURL);


        using (WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResult = Reader.ReadToEnd();
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                returnObj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(soapResult);
            }

        }
        return returnObj;
    }
```

and that's the call of it:

```
var obj = new {
            LoginName=UserName,
            Password= Password,
            ApiLoginName=WebAPIUserName,
            ApiPassword= WebAPIPassword,
            ExpiryDays=ExpiryDays
        };
UserDS oUser = new UserDS();
oUser = WebAPIHelper.getObjectDataRequest("User", "LoginUserState",oUser,obj);
```

when I use the dynamic type it's return an error 
:

```
  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' to 'UserDS'
```

Comment: Use generics, i.e. `public static T GetObjectDataRequest<T>(string ControllerName, string ActionName, object Params)` and `return js.Deserialize<T>(soapResult)`. Please note that I also removed returnObj altogether, because you never use it as input and you can just safely return from within a using directive. You can then call it by `var oUser = WebAPIHelper.GetObjectDataRequest<UserDS>("User", "LoginUserState", obj)`.

Comment: @ckuri Thank you very much it's working .Please set it as an answer.

Comment: By your proposal I changed my comment to a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics. For details see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods.

In this case the method signature would be

```
public static T GetObjectDataRequest<T>(string ControllerName, string ActionName, object Params);
```

The generic argument `T` is here a placeholder for the proper type which will be provider by the method caller.

Within the method you just do:

```
return js.Deserialize<T>(soapResult);
```

Please note that I also removed `returnObj` altogether, because you never use it as input and you can just safely return from within a using directive.

You can then call the method by:

```
var oUser = WebAPIHelper.GetObjectDataRequest<UserDS>("User", "LoginUserState", obj);
```